# Prove a polynomial is the general solution of $n^{th}$ order Euler's equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Suppose I have an Euler's equation: $$\begin{align*}
a_nt^n x^{(n)}+a_{n-1}t^{n-1}x^{(n-1)}+\cdots +a_1tx'+a_nx=0 &&(1)
\end{align*}$$  Suppose $t^r$ where $t>0$ is the solution of this equation, then plug it in $(1)$ we have   $$\begin{align*}
a_nr(r-1)\cdots (r-(n-1))+\cdots +a_1r+a_0=0 &&(2)
\end{align*}$$ By the Fundamental theorem of algebra, I can factor $(2)$ to be $$\begin{align*}
(r-r_1)^{m_1}(r-r_2)^{m_2}\cdots (r-r_k)^{m_k}=0 && (3)
\end{align*}$$ Thus $t^r$ is a solution of $(1)$ $\iff$ $r$ is one of $r_1,\cdots ,r_k$ .

Then I can know that for all $t>0$ , $t^{r_i}$ where $i=1,\ldots ,k$  is a solution of $(1)$ .

If  $Q_j$ is a polynomial with degree $m_j-1$ where $m_j$ is from $(3)$ and also $r_j$ are roots from $(3)$, then is there a way to prove that any function in the form $$\begin{align*}
f(t)=t^{r_1}Q_1(\ln t)+t^{r_2}Q_2(\ln t)+\cdots +t^{r_k}Q_k(\ln t) && (4)
\end{align*}$$ is a solution of $(1)$ ?

I basically have no idea to approach this problem. Any help on this? Thanks.

Comment: Apply the substitution $t=e^s$, $x(t)=u(s)$ to get a linear DE with constant coefficients and compare with claims to solution bases and the method of "unknown parameters".